# getting data on hourly basis from couchdb with millions of objects

Tags: dictionary, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, couchdb, reduce

I have a couchdb database setup at a AWS EC2 medium on-demand instance, there are around 4 million objects in it, with growing rate of around 100 objects per second.

I want to write some map/reduce queries on top of it, but it takes forever for my map jobs to complete.
SO I am wondering if i should copy over the data to some other machine, and delete all data here on the master machine, keeping it clean, and i should rather write my map jobs on the second instance where the data is copied; i am also thinking of moving over this data to a s3 instance, and keep just one week's data here.

Am i thinking in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for such a big database you can only use build-in reduce functions:

- _sum
- _count
- _stats

These functions works MUCH faster than javascript ones. And this is the only possible option for huge databases.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own [View Server](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server) or use one of the available [implementations](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server#Implementations) to test if that helps with performance.